# Mob Creation Using forge api on minecraft1.8

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

First off sorry for being so incoherient before was my first time even asking a question here.

So heres the problem. Im using the forge api for modding minecraft which i am running through eclipse. The version i am attempting to mod is version 1.8 and 1.8 has brought in new changes as far as i can see as to how things are rendered.

What i am attempting to do is create a mob which i can spawn for testing reasons. i want to use a basic humanoid model and transpose a custom (stevelike) skin on top of it. (i am ignoring behaviour and sounds etc for the moment i just want it to spawn and then i can concentrate on the extra bits).

I have made a class for the mob which extends entity creature and i have attempted to add it to the list of entities.

```
package com.drhydrolics.disccraft.entities;

import com.sun.prism.paint.Color;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityCreature;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityRegistry;

public class DEATH extends EntityCreature{

    public DEATH(World worldIn) {
        super(worldIn);
        int entityId =  EntityRegistry.findGlobalUniqueEntityId();
        EntityRegistry.registerGlobalEntityID(DEATH.class, "DEATH",  entityId);
        EntityRegistry.registerGlobalEntityID(DEATH.class, "DEATH", entityId, 1, 1);

    }




}
```

While trying to find where the texture is applied to the class i found the RenderManager and skeletonRenderer and i added my custom mob to the renderManager class
package net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity;

```
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import java.util.Map;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.BlockBed;
import net.minecraft.block.state.IBlockState;
import net.minecraft.client.entity.AbstractClientPlayer;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.FontRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelChicken;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelCow;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelHorse;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelOcelot;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelPig;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelRabbit;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelSheep2;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelSlime;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelSquid;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelWolf;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelZombie;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.OpenGlHelper;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderGlobal;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.Tessellator;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.WorldRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.culling.ICamera;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderEnderCrystal;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderWitherSkull;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.GameSettings;
import net.minecraft.crash.CrashReport;
import net.minecraft.crash.CrashReportCategory;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLeashKnot;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.ai.EntityMinecartMobSpawner;
import net.minecraft.entity.boss.EntityDragon;
import net.minecraft.entity.boss.EntityWither;
import net.minecraft.entity.effect.EntityLightningBolt;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityArmorStand;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityBoat;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityEnderCrystal;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityEnderEye;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityEnderPearl;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityExpBottle;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityFallingBlock;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityFireworkRocket;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityItem;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityItemFrame;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityMinecart;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityMinecartTNT;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityPainting;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityTNTPrimed;
import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityXPOrb;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityBlaze;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityCaveSpider;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityCreeper;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityEnderman;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityEndermite;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityGhast;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityGiantZombie;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityGuardian;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityIronGolem;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityMagmaCube;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityPigZombie;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntitySilverfish;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntitySkeleton;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntitySlime;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntitySnowman;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntitySpider;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityWitch;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityZombie;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityBat;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityChicken;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityCow;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityHorse;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityMooshroom;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityOcelot;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityPig;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityRabbit;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntitySheep;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntitySquid;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityVillager;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityWolf;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityArrow;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityEgg;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityFishHook;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityLargeFireball;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityPotion;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntitySmallFireball;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntitySnowball;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityWitherSkull;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.util.AxisAlignedBB;
import net.minecraft.util.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumFacing;
import net.minecraft.util.ReportedException;
import net.minecraft.util.Vec3;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;

@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public class RenderManager
{
    public Map entityRenderMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    private Map skinMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    private RenderPlayer field_178637_m;
    private FontRenderer textRenderer;
    private double renderPosX;
    private double renderPosY;
    private double renderPosZ;
    public TextureManager renderEngine;
    public World worldObj;
    public Entity livingPlayer;
    public Entity pointedEntity;
    public float playerViewY;
    public float playerViewX;
    public GameSettings options;
    public double viewerPosX;
    public double viewerPosY;
    public double viewerPosZ;
    private boolean renderOutlines = false;
    private boolean renderShadow = true;
    private boolean debugBoundingBox = false;
    private static final String __OBFID = "CL_00000991";

    public RenderManager(TextureManager p_i46180_1_, RenderItem p_i46180_2_)
    {
        this.renderEngine = p_i46180_1_;
        this.entityRenderMap.put(DEATH.class, new RenderDEATH(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityCaveSpider.class, new RenderCaveSpider(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySpider.class, new RenderSpider(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityPig.class, new RenderPig(this, new ModelPig(), 0.7F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySheep.class, new RenderSheep(this, new ModelSheep2(), 0.7F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityCow.class, new RenderCow(this, new ModelCow(), 0.7F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityMooshroom.class, new RenderMooshroom(this, new ModelCow(), 0.7F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityWolf.class, new RenderWolf(this, new ModelWolf(), 0.5F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityChicken.class, new RenderChicken(this, new ModelChicken(), 0.3F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityOcelot.class, new RenderOcelot(this, new ModelOcelot(), 0.4F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityRabbit.class, new RenderRabbit(this, new ModelRabbit(), 0.3F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySilverfish.class, new RenderSilverfish(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityEndermite.class, new RenderEndermite(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityCreeper.class, new RenderCreeper(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityEnderman.class, new RenderEnderman(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySnowman.class, new RenderSnowMan(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySkeleton.class, new RenderSkeleton(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityWitch.class, new RenderWitch(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityBlaze.class, new RenderBlaze(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityPigZombie.class, new RenderPigZombie(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityZombie.class, new RenderZombie(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySlime.class, new RenderSlime(this, new ModelSlime(16), 0.25F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityMagmaCube.class, new RenderMagmaCube(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityGiantZombie.class, new RenderGiantZombie(this, new ModelZombie(), 0.5F, 6.0F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityGhast.class, new RenderGhast(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySquid.class, new RenderSquid(this, new ModelSquid(), 0.7F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityVillager.class, new RenderVillager(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityIronGolem.class, new RenderIronGolem(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityBat.class, new RenderBat(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityGuardian.class, new RenderGuardian(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityDragon.class, new RenderDragon(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityEnderCrystal.class, new RenderEnderCrystal(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityWither.class, new RenderWither(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(Entity.class, new RenderEntity(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityPainting.class, new RenderPainting(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityItemFrame.class, new RenderItemFrame(this, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityLeashKnot.class, new RenderLeashKnot(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityArrow.class, new RenderArrow(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySnowball.class, new RenderSnowball(this, Items.snowball, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityEnderPearl.class, new RenderSnowball(this, Items.ender_pearl, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityEnderEye.class, new RenderSnowball(this, Items.ender_eye, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityEgg.class, new RenderSnowball(this, Items.egg, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityPotion.class, new RenderPotion(this, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityExpBottle.class, new RenderSnowball(this, Items.experience_bottle, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityFireworkRocket.class, new RenderSnowball(this, Items.fireworks, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityLargeFireball.class, new RenderFireball(this, 2.0F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntitySmallFireball.class, new RenderFireball(this, 0.5F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityWitherSkull.class, new RenderWitherSkull(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityItem.class, new RenderEntityItem(this, p_i46180_2_));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityXPOrb.class, new RenderXPOrb(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityTNTPrimed.class, new RenderTNTPrimed(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityFallingBlock.class, new RenderFallingBlock(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityArmorStand.class, new ArmorStandRenderer(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityMinecartTNT.class, new RenderTntMinecart(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityMinecartMobSpawner.class, new RenderMinecartMobSpawner(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityMinecart.class, new RenderMinecart(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityBoat.class, new RenderBoat(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityFishHook.class, new RenderFish(this));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityHorse.class, new RenderHorse(this, new ModelHorse(), 0.75F));
        this.entityRenderMap.put(EntityLightningBolt.class, new RenderLightningBolt(this));
        this.field_178637_m = new RenderPlayer(this);
        this.skinMap.put("default", this.field_178637_m);
        this.skinMap.put("slim", new RenderPlayer(this, true));
    }

    public void setRenderPosition(double p_178628_1_, double p_178628_3_, double p_178628_5_)
    {
        this.renderPosX = p_178628_1_;
        this.renderPosY = p_178628_3_;
        this.renderPosZ = p_178628_5_;
    }

    public Render getEntityClassRenderObject(Class p_78715_1_)
    {
        Render render = (Render)this.entityRenderMap.get(p_78715_1_);

        if (render == null && p_78715_1_ != Entity.class)
        {
            render = this.getEntityClassRenderObject(p_78715_1_.getSuperclass());
            this.entityRenderMap.put(p_78715_1_, render);
        }

        return render;
    }

    public Render getEntityRenderObject(Entity p_78713_1_)
    {
        if (p_78713_1_ instanceof AbstractClientPlayer)
        {
            String s = ((AbstractClientPlayer)p_78713_1_).getSkinType();
            RenderPlayer renderplayer = (RenderPlayer)this.skinMap.get(s);
            return renderplayer != null ? renderplayer : this.field_178637_m;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.getEntityClassRenderObject(p_78713_1_.getClass());
        }
    }

    public void cacheActiveRenderInfo(World worldIn, FontRenderer p_180597_2_, Entity p_180597_3_, Entity p_180597_4_, GameSettings p_180597_5_, float p_180597_6_)
    {
        this.worldObj = worldIn;
        this.options = p_180597_5_;
        this.livingPlayer = p_180597_3_;
        this.pointedEntity = p_180597_4_;
        this.textRenderer = p_180597_2_;

        if (p_180597_3_ instanceof EntityLivingBase && ((EntityLivingBase)p_180597_3_).isPlayerSleeping())
        {
            IBlockState iblockstate = worldIn.getBlockState(new BlockPos(p_180597_3_));
            Block block = iblockstate.getBlock();

            if (block.isBed(worldIn, new BlockPos(p_180597_3_), (EntityLivingBase)p_180597_3_))
            {
                int i = block.getBedDirection(worldIn, new BlockPos(p_180597_3_)).getHorizontalIndex();
                this.playerViewY = (float)(i * 90 + 180);
                this.playerViewX = 0.0F;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.playerViewY = p_180597_3_.prevRotationYaw + (p_180597_3_.rotationYaw - p_180597_3_.prevRotationYaw) * p_180597_6_;
            this.playerViewX = p_180597_3_.prevRotationPitch + (p_180597_3_.rotationPitch - p_180597_3_.prevRotationPitch) * p_180597_6_;
        }

        if (p_180597_5_.thirdPersonView == 2)
        {
            this.playerViewY += 180.0F;
        }

        this.viewerPosX = p_180597_3_.lastTickPosX + (p_180597_3_.posX - p_180597_3_.lastTickPosX) * (double)p_180597_6_;
        this.viewerPosY = p_180597_3_.lastTickPosY + (p_180597_3_.posY - p_180597_3_.lastTickPosY) * (double)p_180597_6_;
        this.viewerPosZ = p_180597_3_.lastTickPosZ + (p_180597_3_.posZ - p_180597_3_.lastTickPosZ) * (double)p_180597_6_;
    }

    public void setPlayerViewY(float p_178631_1_)
    {
        this.playerViewY = p_178631_1_;
    }

    public boolean isRenderShadow()
    {
        return this.renderShadow;
    }

    public void setRenderShadow(boolean p_178633_1_)
    {
        this.renderShadow = p_178633_1_;
    }

    public void setDebugBoundingBox(boolean p_178629_1_)
    {
        this.debugBoundingBox = p_178629_1_;
    }

    public boolean isDebugBoundingBox()
    {
        return this.debugBoundingBox;
    }

    public boolean renderEntitySimple(Entity p_147937_1_, float p_147937_2_)
    {
        return this.renderEntityStatic(p_147937_1_, p_147937_2_, false);
    }

    public boolean shouldRender(Entity p_178635_1_, ICamera p_178635_2_, double p_178635_3_, double p_178635_5_, double p_178635_7_)
    {
        Render render = this.getEntityRenderObject(p_178635_1_);
        return render != null && render.shouldRender(p_178635_1_, p_178635_2_, p_178635_3_, p_178635_5_, p_178635_7_);
    }

    public boolean renderEntityStatic(Entity entity, float partialTicks, boolean p_147936_3_)
    {
        if (entity.ticksExisted == 0)
        {
            entity.lastTickPosX = entity.posX;
            entity.lastTickPosY = entity.posY;
            entity.lastTickPosZ = entity.posZ;
        }

        double d0 = entity.lastTickPosX + (entity.posX - entity.lastTickPosX) * (double)partialTicks;
        double d1 = entity.lastTickPosY + (entity.posY - entity.lastTickPosY) * (double)partialTicks;
        double d2 = entity.lastTickPosZ + (entity.posZ - entity.lastTickPosZ) * (double)partialTicks;
        float f1 = entity.prevRotationYaw + (entity.rotationYaw - entity.prevRotationYaw) * partialTicks;
        int i = entity.getBrightnessForRender(partialTicks);

        if (entity.isBurning())
        {
            i = 15728880;
        }

        int j = i % 65536;
        int k = i / 65536;
        OpenGlHelper.setLightmapTextureCoords(OpenGlHelper.lightmapTexUnit, (float)j / 1.0F, (float)k / 1.0F);
        GlStateManager.color(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
        return this.doRenderEntity(entity, d0 - this.renderPosX, d1 - this.renderPosY, d2 - this.renderPosZ, f1, partialTicks, p_147936_3_);
    }

    public void renderWitherSkull(Entity p_178630_1_, float p_178630_2_)
    {
        double d0 = p_178630_1_.lastTickPosX + (p_178630_1_.posX - p_178630_1_.lastTickPosX) * (double)p_178630_2_;
        double d1 = p_178630_1_.lastTickPosY + (p_178630_1_.posY - p_178630_1_.lastTickPosY) * (double)p_178630_2_;
        double d2 = p_178630_1_.lastTickPosZ + (p_178630_1_.posZ - p_178630_1_.lastTickPosZ) * (double)p_178630_2_;
        Render render = this.getEntityRenderObject(p_178630_1_);

        if (render != null && this.renderEngine != null)
        {
            int i = p_178630_1_.getBrightnessForRender(p_178630_2_);
            int j = i % 65536;
            int k = i / 65536;
            OpenGlHelper.setLightmapTextureCoords(OpenGlHelper.lightmapTexUnit, (float)j / 1.0F, (float)k / 1.0F);
            GlStateManager.color(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
            render.renderName(p_178630_1_, d0 - this.renderPosX, d1 - this.renderPosY, d2 - this.renderPosZ);
        }
    }

    public boolean renderEntityWithPosYaw(Entity p_147940_1_, double p_147940_2_, double p_147940_4_, double p_147940_6_, float p_147940_8_, float p_147940_9_)
    {
        return this.doRenderEntity(p_147940_1_, p_147940_2_, p_147940_4_, p_147940_6_, p_147940_8_, p_147940_9_, false);
    }

    public boolean doRenderEntity(Entity entity, double x, double y, double z, float p_147939_8_, float partialTicks, boolean p_147939_10_)
    {
        Render render = null;

        try
        {
            render = this.getEntityRenderObject(entity);

            if (render != null && this.renderEngine != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (render instanceof RendererLivingEntity)
                    {
                        ((RendererLivingEntity)render).setRenderOutlines(this.renderOutlines);
                    }

                    render.doRender(entity, x, y, z, p_147939_8_, partialTicks);
                }
                catch (Throwable throwable2)
                {
                    throw new ReportedException(CrashReport.makeCrashReport(throwable2, "Rendering entity in world"));
                }

                try
                {
                    if (!this.renderOutlines)
                    {
                        render.doRenderShadowAndFire(entity, x, y, z, p_147939_8_, partialTicks);
                    }
                }
                catch (Throwable throwable1)
                {
                    throw new ReportedException(CrashReport.makeCrashReport(throwable1, "Post-rendering entity in world"));
                }

                if (this.debugBoundingBox && !entity.isInvisible() && !p_147939_10_)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.renderDebugBoundingBox(entity, x, y, z, p_147939_8_, partialTicks);
                    }
                    catch (Throwable throwable)
                    {
                        throw new ReportedException(CrashReport.makeCrashReport(throwable, "Rendering entity hitbox in world"));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (this.renderEngine != null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable3)
        {
            CrashReport crashreport = CrashReport.makeCrashReport(throwable3, "Rendering entity in world");
            CrashReportCategory crashreportcategory = crashreport.makeCategory("Entity being rendered");
            entity.addEntityCrashInfo(crashreportcategory);
            CrashReportCategory crashreportcategory1 = crashreport.makeCategory("Renderer details");
            crashreportcategory1.addCrashSection("Assigned renderer", render);
            crashreportcategory1.addCrashSection("Location", CrashReportCategory.getCoordinateInfo(x, y, z));
            crashreportcategory1.addCrashSection("Rotation", Float.valueOf(p_147939_8_));
            crashreportcategory1.addCrashSection("Delta", Float.valueOf(partialTicks));
            throw new ReportedException(crashreport);
        }
    }

    private void renderDebugBoundingBox(Entity p_85094_1_, double p_85094_2_, double p_85094_4_, double p_85094_6_, float p_85094_8_, float p_85094_9_)
    {
        GlStateManager.depthMask(false);
        GlStateManager.disableTexture2D();
        GlStateManager.disableLighting();
        GlStateManager.disableCull();
        GlStateManager.disableBlend();
        float f2 = p_85094_1_.width / 2.0F;
        AxisAlignedBB axisalignedbb = p_85094_1_.getEntityBoundingBox();
        AxisAlignedBB axisalignedbb1 = new AxisAlignedBB(axisalignedbb.minX - p_85094_1_.posX + p_85094_2_, axisalignedbb.minY - p_85094_1_.posY + p_85094_4_, axisalignedbb.minZ - p_85094_1_.posZ + p_85094_6_, axisalignedbb.maxX - p_85094_1_.posX + p_85094_2_, axisalignedbb.maxY - p_85094_1_.posY + p_85094_4_, axisalignedbb.maxZ - p_85094_1_.posZ + p_85094_6_);
        RenderGlobal.drawOutlinedBoundingBox(axisalignedbb1, 16777215);

        if (p_85094_1_ instanceof EntityLivingBase)
        {
            float f3 = 0.01F;
            RenderGlobal.drawOutlinedBoundingBox(new AxisAlignedBB(p_85094_2_ - (double)f2, p_85094_4_ + (double)p_85094_1_.getEyeHeight() - 0.009999999776482582D, p_85094_6_ - (double)f2, p_85094_2_ + (double)f2, p_85094_4_ + (double)p_85094_1_.getEyeHeight() + 0.009999999776482582D, p_85094_6_ + (double)f2), 16711680);
        }

        Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.getInstance();
        WorldRenderer worldrenderer = tessellator.getWorldRenderer();
        Vec3 vec3 = p_85094_1_.getLook(p_85094_9_);
        worldrenderer.startDrawing(3);
        worldrenderer.setColorOpaque_I(255);
        worldrenderer.addVertex(p_85094_2_, p_85094_4_ + (double)p_85094_1_.getEyeHeight(), p_85094_6_);
        worldrenderer.addVertex(p_85094_2_ + vec3.xCoord * 2.0D, p_85094_4_ + (double)p_85094_1_.getEyeHeight() + vec3.yCoord * 2.0D, p_85094_6_ + vec3.zCoord * 2.0D);
        tessellator.draw();
        GlStateManager.enableTexture2D();
        GlStateManager.enableLighting();
        GlStateManager.enableCull();
        GlStateManager.disableBlend();
        GlStateManager.depthMask(true);
    }

    public void set(World worldIn)
    {
        this.worldObj = worldIn;
    }

    public double getDistanceToCamera(double p_78714_1_, double p_78714_3_, double p_78714_5_)
    {
        double d3 = p_78714_1_ - this.viewerPosX;
        double d4 = p_78714_3_ - this.viewerPosY;
        double d5 = p_78714_5_ - this.viewerPosZ;
        return d3 * d3 + d4 * d4 + d5 * d5;
    }

    public FontRenderer getFontRenderer()
    {
        return this.textRenderer;
    }

    public void setRenderOutlines(boolean p_178632_1_)
    {
        this.renderOutlines = p_178632_1_;
    }
}
```

finally i have made a render DEATH class which extends skeleton which i extended from skeleton renderer in the hope of getting something working but im hitting my head against a wall now package com.drhydrolics.disccraft.entities.Renderers;

```
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderSkeleton;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class renderDEATH extends RenderSkeleton {

    public renderDEATH(RenderManager p_i46143_1_) {
        super(p_i46143_1_);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static final ResourceLocation DeathTextures = new ResourceLocation("assets/textures/entities/DEATH.png");


}
```

Id really appriciate any help, and if ive done anything wrong in formatting or how i aske dthe question please point it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Eek.. Lets get this back to good shape.

You want to avoid changing any vanilla Minecraft code and only use it as an absolute last resort. You are actually pretty close.

I would scrap what you have and start again, only due to the fact that unless you start working with custom models, textures and classes now, it will be very difficult to change over later.

You are supposed to use the registerModEntity method now but for this I will be showing you how to use the registerGlobalEntityID method

Ok, lets get started:

Go to Youtube and follow Mr.Crayfish's guides to setting up a modding environment in 1.8. (This is to ensure you have the common and client proxy set up correctly)

Now, add the following method of mine into your init() class:

```
public static void registerSpawnEntity(Class entityClass, String name, int id, int primaryColor, int secondaryColor, boolean addSpawn, EnumCreatureType typeOfCreature) 
{
    EntityRegistry.registerGlobalEntityID(entityClass, name, id, primaryColor, secondaryColor);
    if(addSpawn)
    {
        EntityRegistry.addSpawn(entityClass, 5, 1, 1, typeOfCreature, new BiomeGenBase[] { BiomeGenBase.plains });
    }
}
```

Now you can call on this method in your **register()** method to register a neat mod entity with a spawn egg ready to go in creative mode. Just call **registerSpawnEntity(...);**

Time to handle the rendering and behaviour.

**Behaviour:** Create a new class and extend a similar class, no extra code necessary.
**Rendering:** Rendering the custom entity requires 3 things: entity must be registered, the entity must have a RenderMyEntity.java file and a ModelMyEntity.java file.

```
// The ModelMyEntity.java file contains the texture location, the texture
// UVs, the 3D render instructions etc.

// The RenderMyEntity.java file should only need to extend the
// RenderOriginalEntity.java file. You can @Override the getEntityTexture
// method to set a custom texture.

// Finally the custom entity needs to have its custom render registered:
RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler(EntityMyEntity.class, new RenderMyEntity(Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderManager()));
```

Provided I haven't forgotten something and you register, extend, model and texture your entities correctly, you should have a neat little spawn egg in creative mode with the colors specified when using the register method. They will also spawn on the plains randomly. you can adjust my code for your needs.

Good luck, hope this helps.